# How C++ turns command line arguments into an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly, command-line-arguments

I would like to how does C++ actually turn the command line arguments into a char array? What "secret" code does this? Where can I view the code that does this (even if it is in assembly, I know some assembly)? I am using Linux, if that helps.

Thank You

Comment: It depends. Why do you need to know?

Comment: I would like to know to help me understand programming better.

Comment: The thing is, there's no one answer. It differs for different compilers and different systems. If you are writing portable C++ then it's simply not something you care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an OS job to manage command line arguments and to put it to the stack during process creation.

For POSIX systems the execution path is:

1. in your program you call the execle/execve/... system call, passing the path to the new process executable and command line arguments.
2. this data go to the kernel
3. the kernel updates its internal structures to take the new process identity into account and allocates the address space for the new process (also kernel purges the old address space if it's not needed anymore). the kernel initializes the process memory with zeros, copying the info from old memory to the new address space at the top of the stack.
4. the kernel puts the new process to the scheduling queue and returns from the `exec()` system call, transferring execution path to the userspace and eventually to the entry point of the process (this is usually routine from `crt0.o` object file, which is linked by default to every executable - this routine calls `main()`).

For Linux, you can see this code here: 
http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/fs/exec.c#L383 :

```
383 /*
384  * 'copy_strings()' copies argument/environment strings from the old
385  * processes's memory to the new process's stack.  The call to get_user_pages()
386  * ensures the destination page is created and not swapped out.
387  */
```

In the `do_execve()` kernel counterpart of userspace `execve()` syscall, at line 1345, `copy_strings()`'s are called, and `copy_strings()` routine actually does the job you're asking about.

Comment: "copy_strings() routine actually does the job you're asking about" - The process he was talking about was the command string being turned into an array. That does not happen in the `copy_strings` function - the command is already an array before that function ever touches it.

Comment: I understood the questions as "how the char array argv[] in the new process memory is created", because calling execve() from C code already takes an array. So, yes, from your point of view, it's a shell that takes command line apart, but that code is quite primitive.

Answer (score 7):

In most (all?) Unix-based operating systems, they are already an array. It's how operating system executes a process there — when a process starts, there is already an array of arguments ready for it.

The code that turns command line into an array lives in a shell (like bash) or any other program that starts another program. `bash` has it's sources available, other programs — it's different.

In Windows, they are one string (which you can get unmodified using `GetCommandLine()` API call), which is parsed by C runtime library to turn it into an array, because the language specification requires them to come as an array.

For programs compiled with Visual C++, the code that does this is included into Visual Studio distributions. You may have to turn on a checkbox that says something like “Include C runtime library source” in installer in order to have it installed.

Comment: No, the environment and arguments are copied by the kernel.

Comment: @EarlGray No — to what? The question is how command line gets parsed into an array, not who copies the array afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually handled by the operating system when it creates the process for the program.  This code could very well be written in C (for example, if the OS is written in C), or it could be in assembly.  To find the code for this, you will probably have to look at the operating system code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: On Windows it's done by the language runtime. Not sure about *nix systems.

Comment: On Windows, CRT does this; on Unix-like systems, it's done by a shell or another program that started the process. I don't know any OS which parses command lines itself.

Comment: @hamstergene I agree. To say that this is "usually" done by the OS seems a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the c runtime library. If you would like to know what that is, look here: [What is the C runtime library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766233/what-is-the-c-runtime-library)

I just created a basic C++ console app using Microsoft Visual Studio and set a breakpoint on the first line of the program. When debugged, the program stops on that line and you call look up the call stack to see the function that calls 'main'. The calling function is part of the c runtime, and this does seem to contain some code that manipulates the command line... I haven't given it a close look, but that's probably where you should start.

Comment: Are you sure this is part of the runtime?  My understanding is that the OS did this, since at the time that the program starts up the memory for these arrays already has to be allocated.

Comment: On Windows CreateProcess takes an LPTSTR for the command line, by the time you're C++ main function sees it, it's in the following parameters: int main(int argc, char *argv[]). It was my best estimation that between one and the other, the C runtime does the conversion by splitting the process's command line arguments up.

Comment: It's not a part of the C runtime library. All that C (and C++) specify is how the `main` function is to be called. How the command line arguments are formed and how `main` is called when the program starts is not specified in either standard.

Comment: @DavidHammen The C and C++ standards do not specify how the runtime libraries are to be implemented. So it's perfectly plausible that some C and C++ runtime libraries parse command lines and convert them into `argc/argv`. And MSVC is one such example.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is not the actual `main()` that is executed first. For example, on Visual Studio it is the function `mainCRTStartup()` that serves as entry point that calls Windows API to retreive and parse the command line (you can see this if you use debugger).

Comment: I think it uses GetCommandLine and CommandLineToArgvW API for that.