# which system software is responsible for Run time check

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, runtime

I thought this would sound a general simple question but I got up this when reading C++ exception specification. that said in one of the book, C++11 now have a keyword 'noexcept' that means no exception will be thrown from a function when it is declared with the function header and that said the reason for this keyword came into existence is `C++ exception specifications are checked at run time rather than at compile time, so they offer no programmer guarantees that all exceptions have been handled.` and hence they conclude two case a function would throw exception or if we are clear if it will never throw, then use `noexcept` for optimization(hopefully)

`void foo() noexcept();`

Here is the main question. Which system software perform those run time checking(I hope not compiler/linker/loader) and also which system software is responsible for allocating memory at run time(dynamic memory allocation) when this are all not taken care by compiler and others?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766233/what-is-the-c-runtime-library

Comment: Ryan, is the compiler link those run time libraries after translation has been done? what type of linking would happen static/dynamic(i think dynamic only)?

Comment: If you take Visual C++ for instance, you have the ability to specify to the compiler (as a project property) whether to link against the DLL version of the CRT, or whether to statically compile it in with your code. In the first option, your exe is smaller because it is loading a DLL at runtime (which your client must have on their computer, the Visual Studio Redistributable) and in the second option your exe is larger because it contains the relevant CRT functions, but no DLL is loaded at runtime.

Comment: i think in my case based on the link you gave libstdc++ gcc/libstdc++6 this two might be the run time library which would take care of those checks am i getting right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you would not say that the "standard library" handles this. Exceptions and exception specifications are rather a core language feature, more fundamental than the standard library.

You could similarly ask, what piece of software ensures that when I call a function in C++, that the caller actually receives the values that I pass in? What piece of software manipulates the stack frame pointers while my program is running?

From the point of view of the standard I would say "the implementation" is responsible for these details. In some languages, like Java for instance, there is a "Java Runtime Environment" which is very clearly responsible for these things, and you could try to study exactly how it does them. In C++ there is no universal runtime environment -- like others have said, the compiler is responsible to generate code that ensures that these things happen, and that code ends up sprinkled throughout your resulting executable. How exactly the compiler achieves its task is implementation-specific, you can't give a general answer beyond what the standard says, and generally it specifies the expected behavior, not the details under the hood.

When you ask

> also which system software is responsible for allocating memory at run time(dynamic memory allocation

this is again an implementation detail, it will differ from compiler to compiler.

Comment: Is there any way i could get the prominent points about those implementation details for GCC?

Comment: I would not expect to find detailed documentation because people aren't really supposed to rely on or think about implementation details, and they might change a lot from version to version. There are surveys and such of the architecture of gcc but for really specific questions you might want to ask a gcc developer in person, perhaps on an irc channel or something (?) Or look at the source code...

Comment: Hope those developers been around in SO :)

Comment: Just a thought, you might get more useful info by writing some simple programs and looking at the generated assembly in using something like [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/)

Comment: Well, I'll do chris                                .

Answer (score 3):

There is no active "system software" checking for exceptions, as you phrase it; rather, throwing an exception is an action taken by the program itself. The program passes the exception back up the stack until the exception matches an exception handler.

If no exception handler matches, then the exception is caught by the bootstrap code (main is not the actual entry point for a typical program, but is where the runtime hands control to the programmer) and the program terminates.

Comment: Just to make things clear ,My question Is not about Exception intact. its about the run time..i took Exception as i got up with this question when reading it :).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is done by the C++ runtime (libstdc++ for example). In case of exceptions, there are some guards added around the functions by the compiler (this is necessary anyway to call destructors in case exception is thrown), and in the case of noexcept, if the function throws (or if it throws other exception than advertised by the throw() specification), terminate() is called by the C++ runtime and the application is shut down.

Memory heap allocations are also (by default) done by the C++ runtime libraries.

Comment: Axalias,its all happened by the run time library(it seems by the way)? i thought libraries are just utilities or pre-written compiled routines which will be linked(statically/dynamically) by some software X for its operation Y. which software access those run time libraries,compiler(i meant is the compiler put some info for linker on the code) ?

Answer (score 2):

Typically the responsible software isn't one clearly identifiable piece of code, but small fragments of code sprinkled through the executable. The compiler translates your code into binary instructions, and `noexcept` is no exception ;).