# Does Go depend on C runtime?

Tags: go, runtime

I can't find info does Go depend on C runtime? If it depends on it, is it statically compiled into the binary to make the application written in Go work everywhere without dependencies?

Here is the topic about [what C runtime is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766233/what-is-the-c-runtime-library)

Comment: Could you elaborate what a "c runtime" is? Go does not depend on inexistent stuff...

Comment: Go does not require any C libraries if that's what you're asking.

Comment: [Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36783409/2285935)

Comment: JimB, so Go-devs reimplemented all low-level stuff?

Comment: @user1432751: The answer depends on what you mean by "low-level stuff". The stdlib is of course implemented entirely in Go. Go however relies on an operating system to provide a number of basic syscalls to run the application.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're talking about executable files provided by a Go compiler, then the answer is "yes or no—it depends":

In most cases, the resulting executable program does *not* depend on a C run-time library.

However, on some platforms under certain circumstances the C runtime library gets *dynamically* linked in.
In particular, this was the case with Go versions < 1.5 on Linux when DNS resolution was used: the runtime depended on the platform's `libc` implementation to handle such resolution.
[In 1.5 this has been reworked](https://golang.org/doc/go1.5#net).

Another possible case is (IIRC) Solaris which provides no stable way to access the kernel's syscalls directly and [requires routing these calls through the platform's `libc`](http://garrett.damore.org/2015/09/on-go-portability-and-system-interfaces.html).

There is another case: using `cgo` which is a layer to interface Go code with foreign C code.  Using `cgo` makes your Go program depend on the C runtime.  Note that you might not use `cgo` directly but one or more of the third-party packages you might be using can use `cgo`, and—transitively—your program ends up depending on the C runtime library.

Comment: The [cgo documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) says that cgo is enabled by default for native builds. So, it looks like one has to set CGO_ENABLED=0 to make sure that there is no a dependency on C runtime.

Answer (score 7):

I think the accepted answer is correct, but a binary which imports the 'net' package usually depends on a c runtime even in go 1.10 and Unix.

Here is the example of the simple echo server:

```
package main

import (
        "io"
        "log"
        "net"
)

func main() {
        ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        for {
                conn, err := ln.Accept()
                if err != nil {
                        log.Print(err)
                        continue
                }

                _, err = io.Copy(conn, conn) // blocked until the client closes the conn.
                if err != nil {
                        log.Print(err)
                        continue
                }

                if err = conn.Close(); err != nil {
                        log.Print(err)
                }
        }
}
```

Build it and check its dependencies:

```
$ go build ./libc_check.go
$ ldd ./libc_check
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe34fc1000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc005d4e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc005984000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc005f6b000)
```

It is because 'the decision of how to run the resolver applies at run time, not build time' as [the release note indicates](https://golang.org/doc/go1.5#net).

To avoid this dependency, use the 'netgo' build tag like this:

```
$ go build -tags netgo ./libc_check.go
$ ldd ./libc_check
        not a dynamic executable
```

Comment: Don't know which version of Go you used, but on 1.11.1 your example produces binary without any dependencies

Comment: Ummm, today I checked my example with 1.11.1 and 1.11.4 on Linux, but the binary still depends on c runtime. I also checked it using the `golang:1.11.1` docker image. So I'm not really sure why the example doesn't work in your env.

Comment: try building with cgo turned off. I tested by cross-compiling on Windows and macOS. The binary had an empty dynamic section.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean LibC, Go does not depend on it. Go has its own standard library that includes implementations of commonly used functions such as file I/O, networking, and memory management, so it does not rely on libc or any other external library.