# Why golang clone syscall abi is diffent from linux kernel clone on x86-64

Tags: linux, go

The linux kernel clone abi definition at glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:

```
The kernel expects:
rax: system call number
rdi: flags
rsi: child_stack
rdx: TID field in parent
r10: TID field in child
r8: thread pointer
```

And the golang clone syscall at go1.11.5/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s:

```
// int32 clone(int32 flags, void *stk, M *mp, G *gp, void (*fn)(void));
TEXT runtime·clone(SB),NOSPLIT,$0
    MOVL    flags+0(FP), DI
    MOVQ    stk+8(FP), SI
    MOVQ    $0, DX
    MOVQ    $0, R10

    // Copy mp, gp, fn off parent stack for use by child.
    // Careful: Linux system call clobbers CX and R11.
    MOVQ    mp+16(FP), R8
    MOVQ    gp+24(FP), R9
    MOVQ    fn+32(FP), R12

    MOVL    $SYS_clone, AX
    SYSCALL
```

So why DX, R10, R8 do not keep to clone-syscall promise?
At the other hand, R9 and R12 seems to be needless.

Please help me.

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: I want to know why runtime.clone traped successfully. It goes against "kernel expects" obviously.

Comment: Go doesn't use glibc.

Comment: Yes, go runtime.clone invokes syscall as glibc.

Comment: @peterSO It's more ["yes or no—it depends"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41721182/1168212) situation. OP included source code where dependencies to `glibc` are defined and asked why they were definded this way and not another

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Reason why DX and R10 are zero

According to the [manpage of clone](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), these are used only when `CLONE_PARENT_SETTID`, `CLONE_CHILD_SETTID` is set.

> CLONE_PARENT_SETTID (since Linux 2.5.49)
>                 Store the child thread ID at the location ptid in the parent's
>                 memory.  (In Linux 2.5.32-2.5.48 there was a flag CLONE_SETTID
>                 that did this.)  The store operation completes before clone()
>                 returns control to user space.
>
> CLONE_CHILD_SETTID (since Linux 2.5.49)
>                 Store the child thread ID at the location ctid in the child's
>                 memory.  The store operation completes before clone() returns
>                 control to user space.

DX and R10 corresponds to `ptid` and `ctid` in this manpage ([Reference](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/)).

Actually, this flag is not set when calling runtime.clone() from os_linux.go: [Source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/52e2126a5ee7c1123ded51874ec0fe0394eabd0a/src/runtime/os_linux.go#L132-L137).

The reason they don't need tid is maybe because it's not a library such as pthread which user does something complicated using tid.

#### What R8, R9, and R12 are used for

In short, R8, R9 and R12 are not used by system call but used to construct the stack after it.

Note that R8 and R9 are passed as argument to system call, but not used by clone (see the reason below), and R12 is preserved after system call, it is safe to use these registers after system call. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call))

Let's see the detail.

internally runtime.clone is called as follows: [Source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/52e2126a5ee7c1123ded51874ec0fe0394eabd0a/src/runtime/os_linux.go#L158)

```
func newosproc(mp *m) {
    stk := unsafe.Pointer(mp.g0.stack.hi)
    ....
    ret := clone(cloneFlags, stk, unsafe.Pointer(mp), unsafe.Pointer(mp.g0), unsafe.Pointer(funcPC(mstart)))
    ....
}
```

Reading [Quick Guide to Go's Assembler](https://golang.org/doc/asm), and the code OP posted, you can see that R8 is pointer to `mp`, and R9 is pointer to `mp.g0` and R12 is pointer to some function which you want to call in the `clone`ed thread. (structure of `m` and `g` looks like this: [Source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/52e2126a5ee7c1123ded51874ec0fe0394eabd0a/src/runtime/runtime2.go#L404) and this: [Source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/52e2126a5ee7c1123ded51874ec0fe0394eabd0a/src/runtime/runtime2.go#L339)
).

R8 is argument to clone which indicates tls(thread local storage), but it is not used unless `CLONE_SETTLS` is set: [Source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8dcd175bc3d50b78413c56d5b17d4bddd77412ef/arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c#L436)

R9 is generally used as 6th argument to system call, but clone does not use it because it only uses 5 arguments([Source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/542d0e583b7b366527175b2b5fc0aad262fa33b0/kernel/fork.c#L2310-L2336)).

R12 is a register which is preserved after system call.

So finally let's see the [source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/1650f1ba0b964a06a242c3318e85b3b46f010614/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s#L540) of runtime.clone. The important thing is after the `SYSCALL`. They are doing some stack setup using R8 and R9 in the child thread which is created, and finally calling R12.

```
// int32 clone(int32 flags, void *stk, M *mp, G *gp, void (*fn)(void));
TEXT runtime·clone(SB),NOSPLIT,$0
    MOVL    flags+0(FP), DI
    MOVQ    stk+8(FP), SI
    MOVQ    $0, DX
    MOVQ    $0, R10

    // Copy mp, gp, fn off parent stack for use by child.
    // Careful: Linux system call clobbers CX and R11.
    MOVQ    mp+16(FP), R8
    MOVQ    gp+24(FP), R9
    MOVQ    fn+32(FP), R12

    MOVL    $SYS_clone, AX
    SYSCALL

    // In parent, return.
    CMPQ    AX, $0
    JEQ 3(PC)
    MOVL    AX, ret+40(FP)
    RET

    // In child, on new stack.
    MOVQ    SI, SP

    // If g or m are nil, skip Go-related setup.
    CMPQ    R8, $0    // m
    JEQ nog
    CMPQ    R9, $0    // g
    JEQ nog

    // Initialize m->procid to Linux tid
    MOVL    $SYS_gettid, AX
    SYSCALL
    MOVQ    AX, m_procid(R8)

    // Set FS to point at m->tls.
    LEAQ    m_tls(R8), DI
    CALL    runtime·settls(SB)

    // In child, set up new stack
    get_tls(CX)
    MOVQ    R8, g_m(R9)
    MOVQ    R9, g(CX)
    CALL    runtime·stackcheck(SB)

nog:
    // Call fn
    CALL    R12

//(omitted)
```

Comment: I had a hope that OP will return. But we have only 2 days left and I think your answer is correct. So: reward for you!

Comment: I return, a little surprise, i thought nobody will care this post. Now i make it clear that R8, R9, R12 is not for raw clone syscall but for passing parameters to child. This also enhanced my understanding about "The raw clone() system call corresponds more closely to fork(2)". Thanks.

Comment: @api I'm glad that you checked answer yourself and cleared my doubts,  because I myself wrote `asm`  many years ago.  "i thought nobody will care this post" - there are people exists who thinks that this question is very good

Comment: @AlexYu stackoverflow is a marvelous place :)