# Clion c++ executable vs C++ library

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, executable

I am new to the C++ language. And when I start building a new project, I can see two options. C++ Executable and C++ Library.

I have tried looking for their difference at a lot of places, but could not get anything. Can someone please guide me to a correct answer on this topic?

Thanks

[For reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiNDH.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're building a self standing program, you'll want an executable.

But you might be building a library of functions/classes that provide utility to someone else or another project.  In that case you'll want other programs to be able to link against the library to access those functions/classes, either statically - to compile the library into their project - or dynamically to fetch stuff the library at runtime.

Comment: For more about libraries see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766233/what-is-the-c-runtime-library, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140061/when-to-use-dynamic-vs-static-libraries and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688200/difference-between-shared-objects-so-static-libraries-a-and-dlls-so?rq=1